# ¿Cómo consultar registro por mes y año?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en sql server 2008 el cual realiza una consulta por mes y año como parámetros deberia devolver algunos datos como fecha, fecha de cierre y estado, el inconveniente que tengo es que me devuelve la fecha de cierre solo si esta dentro del mes por ejemplo si la fecha de cierre del mes fue registrado el 01/02/2023 no devuelve la fecha de cierre

```html
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Cierre_Comprobar]
@mes int, @año int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fechaAux DATE = '01-'+RTRIM(@mes)+'-'+RTRIM(@año); --primer dia del mes

    SET @fechaAux = (SELECT DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@fechaAux)+1,0)))); --ultimo dia del mes
                
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mybd2..MOVISUELDO WHERE CODTIPOMOV=20 AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux)
    
    BEGIN
        
            SELECT DISTINCT
            CASE WHEN P.CODCIERRE IS NULL THEN 'Generado' ELSE 'Cerrado' END Estado
            ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@fechaAux,103) Fecha
            ,(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,fechaCierre,103) FROM mybd1..ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION WHERE MONTH(fechaCierre)=MONTH(@fechaAux) AND YEAR(fechaCierre)=YEAR(@fechaAux))
            ,NUMMOVI Comisión
            ,(SELECT NUMMOVI FROM mybd12..MOVISUELDO WHERE CODTIPOMOV = 45 AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux) Flete
            ,(SELECT NUMMOVI FROM mybd2..MOVISUELDO WHERE CODTIPOMOV = 97 AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux) Flete_Taka
            ,(SELECT NUMMOVI FROM mybd2..MOVISUELDO WHERE CODTIPOMOV = 165 AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux) IVA
            ,(SELECT NUMMOVI FROM mybd2..MOVISUELDO WHERE CODTIPOMOV = 166 AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux) Retención
        FROM
            mybd2..MOVISUELDO M
        LEFT JOIN
            mybd2..PROCESOCIERRE P ON P.FECHAHASTA=@fechaAux
        WHERE
            m.CODTIPOMOV IN (20)
            AND FECHAMOVI=@fechaAux

                
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            'Pendiente'
            ,''
            ,''
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0
    
    END   

END
```

El valor de la columna fecha de cierre devuelve nulo en el caso de que los parametros enviados sean 01 enero y 2023 año ya que la fecha de cierre es 01/02/2023 ¿Alguien podria ayudarme por favor se los agradeceria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el script de la tabla movisueldo

```js
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MOVISUELDO](
    [CODMOVI] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [CODTIPOMOV] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CODUSUARIO] [numeric](9, 0) NULL,
    [CODMONEDA] [numeric](9, 0) NULL,
    [CODEMPRESA] [numeric](9, 0) NULL,
    [NUMMOVI] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [FECHAMOVI] [datetime] NULL,
    [COTIZACION1] [numeric](18, 5) NULL,
    [COTIZACION2] [numeric](18, 5) NULL,
    [FECGRA] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [XPKMOVISUELDO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

Y estos son algunos datos que están cargados en la tabla MOVISUELDO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL script de la tabla ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION

```js
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION](
    [numLiquidacion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [transportista] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fechaCierre] [date] NOT NULL,
    [codMovimiento] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ADDUSER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ADDDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UPDUSER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UPDDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

Y algunos datos cargados en la tabla ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo deberia recuperar una columna por ejemplo el cierre del mes de enero en la tabla ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION fue cerrada el 2023-02-02 pero la columna fechacierre en la consulta devuelve nulo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No ocurre eso si el mes de cierre fue registrada en la tabla ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION en el mismo mes y año enviados como parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa [ask], pero sobre todo [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yo creo que el problema está en esta linea `,(SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,fechaCierre,103)`. Es dificil de verificar, ya que no se las tablas, pero puede que el null salga porque esta consulta arroja varios resultados en lugar de 1. Si solo necesitas uno puede ponerle un `select top 1 convert(varchar,fechacierre, 103)....`

Comment: ¿Como se relaciona la fecha de cierre 01/02/2023 con el periodo 01/2023?

Comment: ¿Cómo defines a que mes corresponde la fecha de cierre?

Comment: Bueno los resultados son producto de tu query porque restringe la fecha de cierre al mes de la fecha de movimiento. Me parece que en vez que la fecha de cierre esté dentro del mes lo que deberías utilizar el número de liquidación para obtener la fecha de de cierre siempre y cuando el nummovi o codmovi estén relacionados

Comment: Mientras no tengas una forma confiable de relacionar las tablas, tus resultados no podrán ser confiables.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un error en la forma en la que creas la fecha auxiliar

```sql
declare @mes int = 5
declare @año int = 2023

--DECLARE @fechaAux DATE = '01-'+RTRIM(@mes)+'-'+RTRIM(@año); --primer dia del mes -->Esta tomando el mes como el día
DECLARE @fechaAux DATE = RTRIM(@mes) + '-01-' + +RTRIM(@año)

select @fechaAux

SET @fechaAux = (SELECT DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@fechaAux)+1,0)))); --ultimo dia del mes

select @fechaAux

select year(@fechaAux), MONTH(@fechaAux)

--Por lo tanto esta linea en tu sp va a fallar 
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,fechaCierre,103) FROM mybd1..ORDENDESALIDA_LIQUIDACION WHERE MONTH(fechaCierre)=MONTH(@fechaAux) AND YEAR(fechaCierre)=YEAR(@fechaAux)

--pues estarías tomando el mes pero tendrías seteado el día en su lugar
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la corrección en la fecha debería solucionar tu inconveniente.

Comment: Por cierto cambia las `ñ`.

Comment: El error que dices está en tu configuración. Tu solución sigue dependiendo de la configuración local.